# How to show clusters in a map?

Tags: django, flutter, plot

I'm building a **Flutter** map and I want show clusters that are storred in a **Django** server database. I want to do a similar view as this but instead of showing all the users location, I want to show the surface that these users are occupying (the surface of a cluster).

PS: I'm using a package named **flutter_map** to display the map.

[image]